# unable to connect mongo with php

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

For integrating mongodb with php I installed mongodb with sudo pecl install mongodb then I checked my php.ini file for the presence of the mongodb.so extension and it was there but whenever I am doing something let say checking for PHP version (PHP --version) it gives the following message

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_string_init_interned
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_string_init_interned
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

composer is not getting an update too. Nothing is working  Please help